# Convert object to array of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some data passed in via a query string and I've converted it to an object like:

```
{
  "Person1_Age": 22,
  "Person1_Height": 170,
  "Person1_Weight": 72,
  "Person2_Age": 27,
  "Person2_Height": 160,
  "Person2_Weight": 56,
}
```

I want to convert this to an array of objects like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Person1",
    "age": "22",
    "height": 170,
    "weight": 72
  },
  {
    "name": "Person2",
    "age": "27",
    "height": 160,
    "weight": 56
  }
]
```

What would be the best way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with `forEach` loop and optional `thisArg` parameter

```js
var data = {
  "Person1_Age": 22,
  "Person1_Height": 170,
  "Person1_Weight": 72,
  "Person2_Age": 27,
  "Person2_Height": 160,
  "Person2_Weight": 56,
}

var result = [];
Object.keys(data).forEach(function(e) {
  var part = e.split('_');
  var person = part[0];
  var p = part[1].toLowerCase();

  if(!this[person]) {
    this[person] = {name: person}
    result.push(this[person]);
  } 
  
  this[person][p] = data[e];
}, {})

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it

```js
var obj = {
  "Person1_Age": 22,
  "Person1_Height": 170,
  "Person1_Weight": 72,
  "Person2_Age": 27,
  "Person2_Height": 160,
  "Person2_Weight": 56,
}

var map = {}, arr = [];

Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(k) {
  var parts = k.split('_'),
      key   = parts.shift().toLowerCase(),
      val   = parts.pop().toLowerCase();

  if (!(key in map)) map[key] = {};
  map[key][val] = obj[k];
});

for (var k in map) {
  map[k].name = k;
  arr.push(map[k]);
}

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(arr, 0, 4) + '</pre>';
```

Comment: Thanks! I accepted the other answer but this is just as good. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hash table for reference and push the object to the Array, if a new hash is found.

```js
var obj = { Person1_Age: 22, Person1_Height: 170, Person1_Weight: 72, Person2_Age: 27, Person2_Height: 160, Person2_Weight: 56 },
    arr = [];

Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(k) {
    var parts = k.split('_');

    if (!this[parts[0]]) {
        this[parts[0]] = { name: parts[0] };
        arr.push(this[parts[0]]);
    }
    this[parts[0]][parts[1].toLowerCase()] = obj[k];
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, this can also be done directly as the result of a `.reduce()` method.

```js
var list = {
  "Person1_Age": 22,
  "Person1_Height": 170,
  "Person1_Weight": 72,
  "Person2_Age": 27,
  "Person2_Height": 160,
  "Person2_Weight": 56
};

var res = Object.keys(list).reduce(function(a, b) {
  var m = b.match(/Person(\d+)_(.+)/);
  (a[m[1] - 1] = a[m[1] - 1] || {name: 'Person' + m[1]})[m[2].toLowerCase()] = list[b];
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```